# Why Share Extension is not working on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, share, ios13, share-extension

I was using a `Share extension` in my app in order to import audio files and it was working on iOS12. Now in iOS 13 is not working anymore, when I press the `share` button my app doesn't appear in the `share sheet`.
I think that maybe something has changed in the plist or similar but I coudn't find any information.
Does anyone have the same problem?

NB: I don't wanna use the `copy` - `paste` strategies, only the share extension.

Comment: I got this issue in iOS13 too. iOS12 was working fine and iOS13 totally blew it

Comment: Actually a lot of apps have disappeared from the share panel in iOS13 so I guess this is a common issue. Only messaging apps seem to have got it working, I even looked at Telegram open source code but couldn't get any useful insights :(

Comment: Share extensions for iOS 13 have a lot of new features and changes. People just haven't updated their apps in time to support the new implementations.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this for iOS 13**

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

      let activityItem = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio", ofType: "mp3")!)

      let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityItem],applicationActivities: nil)
      activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

      self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this
´´´
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.myShareUrlFunction()
}
´´´

Answer (score 0):

For IOS 13 you Should add below code inside your open url method.

```
UISceneOpenExternalURLOptions * options = [[UISceneOpenExternalURLOptions alloc] init];
options.universalLinksOnly = false;
```